# Why is my text flowing outside my Paragraph Element?

Tags: html, css

I have a widget that will display a listing of comments.  The intent is...for the element to simply automatically expand to display the comment (text).

However, no matter what I try, either the element (itself) expands beyond the page...or the text flows beyond the bounds of the element(s).

I would like it to:

- Adjust to parents width (if possible)
- Auto-expand the height to fully-display the comment (if possible)

I've been trying:

- Combinations of fixing inline-size, word-wrapping & overflow

But I cant seem to make it work

```css
.commenting-context {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #B9B9B4;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #2e6da4;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #2e6da4;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #2e6da4;
}

.commenting-context section header {}

.commenting-context section header h5 {
  color: #B4B4B3;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.commenting-context section header h5 .topic {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.commenting-context .comment-gallery {
  display: none;
}

.commenting-context .comment-gallery .comment {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.commenting-context .comment-gallery .comment:first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.commenting-context .comment-gallery .comment header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.commenting-context .comment-gallery .comment header .author {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.commenting-context .comment-gallery .comment header .author.system {
  color: #ccc;
}

.commenting-context .comment-gallery .comment header .title {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.commenting-context .comment-gallery .comment header .datetime {
  color: #B4B4B3;
}

.commenting-context .comment-gallery .comment p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  inline-size: 400px;
}

.commenting-context .working-status {
  border: 1px solid #E7E2E2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.commenting-context .working-status img {
  height: 50px;
}

.commenting-context .working-status p {
  color: #09347a;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Comment Widget -->
<div class="commenting-context" data-context-id="0" data-context-fullname="">

  <!-- Comment Header -->
  <section>
    <header class="clearfix">
      <h5 class="pull-left">Comments&nbsp;for&nbsp;<span class="topic"></span></h5>
    </header>
  </section>

  <!-- Comment Gallery -->
  <section class="comment-gallery"></section>

  <!-- Working Message -->
  <div class="working-status">
    <center>
      <img src="/Content/Images/green-working-spinner.gif" />
      <p>Working</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Comment -->
<article class="comment" data-id="0" data-commenting-id="0" data-user-id="0" data-is-system-comment="false">
  <header class="clearfix">
    <span class="datetime"></span>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <span class="author text-right"></span>
      <span class="title text-right"></span>
    </div>
  </header>
  <p></p>
  <hr />
</article>
```

VISUAL: 
[image]

Comment: Text content of a `p` tag should handle overflow / breaks by default. I'd be curious to see the inheritance tree of that element if you right clicked and inspected it. My first guess is there's some other css effecting it as your culprit like a `white-space: nowrap` from something else.

Comment: @ChrisW. Actually, kendo's ".k-grid td" has that...and when I uncheck it...all the text flattens into "garble".  I'm guessing it isn't figuring-out the height either.  If you know the fix...could you please submit an answer? Thanks

Comment: So the contents of `p` in this case are getting a nowrap as a child of a table cell class? I assume because maybe they use ellipsis on long strings as cell content? If that's the case just cancel it out by applying like `white-space: normal` to the `p` content. I'd need to see a reproducible example to say exactly but it's definitely fixable.

Comment: OKAY...whoever voted it down...if you're going to vote is down at least leave a comment as to why.

Comment: @ChrisW. OKAY...the actual fix was "WHITE-SPACE: normal;" and "LINE-HEIGHT: normal;".  Since you got closest...if you create an answer...I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, often for UX purposes many third party data tables will apply a `white-space: nowrap` to a cells contents to apply an ellipsis with a hover tooltip to save on screen real estate in cases with long content strings (or sometimes they'll toggle the `table-layout` property on the table itself from `auto` to `fixed` for other scenarios. Either can effect content strings in various cases.

In this case a definition of `white-space: nowrap` is apparently applied accompanied by the `line-height` restriction you identified. So by overriding these properties to allow the wrapping then the cells content will in invoke the default `overflow` and `word-break` definitions to allow the user agent rendering it to perform like a paragraph would normally behave.

Glad you got your remedy!

Answer (score 1):

Use a mix of max-width, and max-content.
Type into this snippet to see how it works.

```js
$("input[type='text']").keyup(function () 
{
  $("#msg")[0].innerHTML = $("input[type='text']")[0].value;
});
```

```css
#limit {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

#msg 
{
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 98%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "limit">
  <div id = "msg">
  </div>
</div>
<input type = 'text'>
```

Answer (score 0):

use position property in css

Position:relative;